# ShortCut Icon Not working On Ice Cream sandwich 4.0 But works fine on SDK < 14 

Tags: android

Shortcut icon created is working fine except in Android 4.0
when clicking on the shortcut it is showing

> THE APP ISN'T INSTALLED

here is my code

```
public class shortcutlauncher extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();

    shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.test", ".loginactivity");

    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    // Sets the custom shortcut's title
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "APP NAME");
    // Set the custom shortcut icon
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon));
    // add the shortcut
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

And then declared activity in Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".shortcutlauncher" 
        android:taskAffinity="" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.test.shortcutlauncher" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: do you mean "SDK < 4" or "SDK < 14"?

Comment: I mean "SDK < 14"  SORRY

Comment: I found the answer it is a simple mistake "shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.test", ".loginactivity");" is reconginzed as com.test./loginactivity in android sdk >14  as i replaced the code as  final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, loginactivity.class);                                                  Don't  Known why the previous code is working fine with android sdk <14